# Position vectors

Tags: kinematics, terminology, vectors

I was reading Kinematics from my textbook. It started off by defining vectors and its two types:
1. *Free vectors* 
2. *Fixed vectors*

That's all good. But then it went on to say that all the vectors we'll be dealing with in 'our' study will be free vectors. After that it defined position vectors. Isn't position vector a fixed vector as we specify it with respect to some coordinate system (as against the *free vectors* my book says we'll be dealing with)? Is my book wrong or am I missing something?

**EDIT**

This is how my book defines the aforementioned terms:

Fixed vector: (I'm quoting the exact statement) In some physical applications, the location or line of application of a vector is important. Such vectors are called localised or *fixed* vectors.

Free vector: (Yet again, quoting the exact statement) In our study (of kinematics I believe) vectors do not have fixed locations. So displacing a vector parallel to itself leaves it unchanged. Such vectors are called *free* vectors.

Comment: Well, how does your textbook define "free vector"?

Comment: @mikuszefski It defines a free vector as a vector which remains unchanged when shifted parallel to itself.

Comment: Then what is a "fixed" vector? In what way does it change when shifted?

Comment: That's interesting: Just out of curiosity, could you also give the definition of a fixed vector?...Actually I think it would be a good idea to put the definitions in your post.

Comment: @velutluna A fixed vector is one whose point of application is fixed.

Comment: May be you can try to read "Euclidean and affine vectors" here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_vector

Comment: @mikuszefski Done.

Comment: To be honest, I believe that the entire definition is not very helpful and unnecessarily mixes concepts of physics and math. Does the book give examples for both cases?

Comment: I agree with @mikuszefski that this seems to be an unnecessary overcomplication. A vector is an arrow with direction and size/magnitude. That's it. If it is a *position* vector, then naturally it must point from some reference point, before this makes sense. If it is a  *displacement* vector, then it doesn't matter since that is just displacing something from whereever it started - it could start anywhere and undergo that displacement. A vector is a vector, and the circumstances / real-life situation may put some extra requirements on it. No need to make it more confusing.

Comment: @mikuszefski and Steeven indeed it's an overcomplication. But it has been troubling me for quite a while. So I thought it'd be best to ask about it here.

Answer (score 1):

I believe your book is wrong in assuming that the only vectors required in the study of Kinematics, at any level, will be free vectors. The position vector is a very fundamental vector in Kinematics, and clearly, it **is a fixed vector.** Why? Because changing it's position will change the position of the object itself, and if that happens, there's no point in defining something as a position vector.